# Flex 4.5 w/ Apple App Store

Tags: ios, apache-flex

I just read on the news that Adobe released Flex 4.5 and it allows creation of apps for all platforms (Android, iOS, Blackberry). I've lost interest in Flash, but the article on Flex stated the apps created are ok to submit to the Apple App Store? Does anyone think this is true? Doesn't Apple want it's developers to stick to XCode and only XCode? I have a hard time believing the article was correct.

http://www.macrumors.com/2011/06/20/adobe-updates-flash-builder-and-flex-to-support-building-ios-applications/

Any input would be appreciated!

Zach

Comment: I answered, but also voted to close as this is not a programming question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does anyone think this is true?

I do; Apple changes their license restrictions quite a while ago; and Adobe announced it would resume development of their Flash to iOS packager.  [Here is some more information](http://blogs.adobe.com/conversations/2010/09/great-news-for-developers.html), back from September 10th, 2010 when Apple changed their restrictions to allow for things like the Adobe iOS Packager.

Adobe has been promoting this fairly heavily.  Here are a few links:

http://www.riagora.com/2011/03/preview-of-flex-on-ios/

http://gregsramblings.com/2011/06/20/finally-its-here-flex-on-ios-android-and-blackberry-playbook/

But, there are plenty more if you want to keep searching.

> Doesn't Apple want it's developers to
>   stick to XCode and only XCode?

I suspect they do.  App lock-in will be huge value add to the iOS platform moving forward.  Whatever you feel about Apple and their platform; they still are the King of Apps.  Cross platform development tools can hinder the value add proposition of their platform.